# Javascript PHP var array puts double quotes in

Tags: javascript, variables

I can't work this one out...

I have a var called data which consists of exactly this..

```
"12-9-2011","13-9-2011","14-9-2011","15-9-2011","16-9-2011"
```

including the quotes

but when i come to use the javascript command `unavailableDates = [data];`

it adds more quotes on either end... how can i stop this..

it makes unavailableDates equal `""12-9-2011","13-9-2011"...15-9-2011","16-9-2011","`

you see with quotes on the ends...

Any way i can stop this ?

Thanks

Lee

Comment: could you please add some code? I don't understand what happens.

Comment: its awkward because its php code parsing to javascript.... but its just added double quotes on either end, where the javascript command has brackets its added double quotes either side of the data var

Answer (score 1):

If you use a string in a literal array it will just be an array with a single string, it won't evaluate the string.

Split the string into an array instead:

```
unavailableDates = data.substr(1, data.length - 2).split('","');
```

Comment: very very close.... just leaves me with an extra unwanted double quotes at the end

Comment: @Lee: Then the `data` variable doesn't contain exactly what you think that it does, or the extra quotes is just an artifact of how you display the result. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/z3vRx/